# R: find smallest difference between columns and return mean value

Tags: r, dplyr

Let's say I have a dataset:

```
ID  resid1  resid2  resid3
A   0,5      0,2    -0,2
B   0,1     -0,3     0,2
C   0,4     -0,1     0,1
D   0,3        0     0,2
E   0,1      0,6    -0,8
```

I would like to find the two columns with the smallest difference in value, and then return the mean value of those two columns in a separate object. The result should be something like:

```
ID  mean
A   0,35
B   0,15
C   0
D   0,25
E   0,35
```

Any assistace greatly appreciated. I am simply at a loss of how to do it (even thoughI am sure there are several easy ways to solve this).

Comment: Do you have `,` or `.`

Comment: I just made the example to make it simpler. Sorry about the confusion, I guess I would have ```.```

Comment: I find some inconsistency in the output you showed.  Plase check if the ``mean` are correct

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution

```
dfout <- cbind(
    df[1],
    mean = apply(df[-1], 1, function(v) {
        vs <- sort(v)
        ind <- which.min(diff(vs))
        mean(vs[ind + 0:1])
    })
)
```

which gives

```
> dfout
  ID mean
1  A 0.35
2  B 0.15
3  C 0.00
4  D 0.25
5  E 0.35
```

**data**

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), resid1 = c(0.5, 
0.1, 0.4, 0.3, 0.1), resid2 = c(0.2, -0.3, -0.1, 0, 0.6), resid3 = c(-0.2, 
0.2, 0.1, 0.2, -0.8)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```